# Plotly with KNN

Tags: plotly, knn, plotly-python

I am classifying my dataset with `knn` with the next code:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(accidentes[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']],accidentes['col4'], train_size=0.7, shuffle=False)
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, algorithm='auto', metric='manhattan')
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
X_test['predictions'] = knn.predict(X_test)
```

But I would like to plot this `knn` classifier with `plotly` in python. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this https://plotly.com/python/knn-classification/ example with your data.